# How to not lose records in full join

Tags: sql, outer-join, vertica

Let's say I have two tables; table A and table shown below:

```
A
Color   ID
Blue    1
Green   2
Red     3

B
Color   ID
Blue    1
Brown   2
Red     3
```

If I were to attempt to join them using a full join, the result would depend on which table I use in the select statement.  For example the following query would produce the following result

```
select A.color, count(*)
from A 
full join B on a.color = B.color
group by 1
order by 1

color   count
Blue    1
Green   1
Red     1
        1
```

If I decided to use B.color in the select statement instead of A.color, I would get the result below:

```
color   count
Blue    1
Brown   1
Red     1
        1
```

How would I get the resultset to include all values for color.  I know I could accomplish using unionall, and I could use a case statement in the select statement to use one when the other is null, but is there another cleaner way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce` to pick up the value from the other table in case the value exists in one table and not the other.

```
select coalesce(A.color,B.color) as color, count(*)
from A 
full join B on a.color = B.color
group by 1
order by 1
```

Comment: What if there was a 3rd table involved with a different color that didn't exist in either table? Does coalesce work with N items?

Comment: yes it works with any number of items. It picks up the first non-null value. Hence ordering is important in `coalesce`.[vertica documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Null/COALESCE.htm)